# Can't parse empty xml property with attribute

Tags: java, jackson, xml-deserialization

I have the following xml:

```
<prog>
    <prop1 attr="attr"> </prop1> 
    <prop2>some</prop2> 
</prog>
```

I have the following class for represent it:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "prog")
public class Prog {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "prop1")
    private String prop1;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "prop2")
    private String prop2;

    //getters, setters
}
```

But it fails with the following error: `Could not read document: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class com.xxx.xxx.entities.ro.Prog] from String value ('some'); no single-String constructor/factory method\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@1bbaaffd; line: 18, column: 36]`

The following xmls CAN be parsed well (using class above):

without attribute

```
<prog>
    <prop1> </prop1> 
    <prop2>some</prop2> 
</prog>
```

empty prop1 (instead of spaces)

```
<prog>
    <prop1 attr="attr"></prop1> 
    <prop2>some</prop2> 
</prog>
```

not empty prop1

```
<prog>
    <prop1 attr="attr"> g</prop1> 
    <prop2>some</prop2> 
</prog>
```

Does original xml valid? And how can I parse it?
Actually I need to skip `attr`, but I also tried to represent it as Object:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class XmlElement {

    @JacksonXmlText
    private String value;

    //getters, setters
}
```

UPDATE:
I invoke parsing while using SpringMVC controllers, but it also reproduces with:

```
String xml = "<prog>" +
        "<prop1 attr=\"att1\"> </prop1>" +
        "<prop2>some</prop2>" +
        "</prog>";
ObjectMapper xmlmapper = new XmlMapper();
Prog prog = xmlmapper.readValue(xml, Prog.class);
```

Comment: Show also the code how do you invoke parser.

Comment: @Andremoniy I have updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works perfectly with `com.fasterxml.jackson` of version `2.7.4`. But it fails with various errors if some of libraries has another version (for example, `jackson-dataformat-xml` of earlier versions). So you have to check which versions of `com.fasterxml.jackson.core`, `jackson-annotations` and `jackson-dataformat-xml` are used, and make them the same.

Comment: I change version to 2.7.4 and it start working (previously I'm using 2.7.3 everywhere). So it was just a bug in previous versions?

Comment: oh, yes,
here is my bug:
https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml/issues/191